# How to Convert From Gene Location to SNP Location

Tags: gene, snp

I am new to this. I have an SNP array composed of digits [0,1,2] for chromosome 21. How do I find the start:end locations for the region that is "21q22.11" step by step?

Comment: It seems your title doesn't really match to the content of your question, could you fix that?

Answer (score 2):

You first need to get the coordinates of the "cytoband" 21q22.11, which I would search for using the [UCSC table browser](https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables?hgsid=791314831_aE2GlksiE79iyiT0FHCRXDZcFwPC). You need the following settings: 
Clade: Mammal
genome: Human
assembly: 
group: Mapping and Sequencing
track: Chromosome Band
table: cytoBand
region: position chr21
output format: BED

(you can leave other options as default)

That will give you a bed file of cytobands on chr21. You'll need to search (e.g. grep) for your cytoband: q22.11.